# Replicate a component used in another page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fullstack

I have two pages in my webapp, A and B.
In page A, I have a component, which I want to use in B.
So I copied the component from A and posted it in B.
It looks like this:

```js
          <Dropdown
              key={`${this.props.selectedStorageClass}_selectedNamespace`}
              itemToString={item => (item ? item.name : '')}
              items={this.props.storageClasses}
              initialSelectedItem={this.props.selectedStorageClass}
              onChange={(target) => setStorageClass(target.selectedItem)}
          />
```

What else Do I need to add. All the examples of Dropdown which I see are fairly simple in nature and I don't know how to make it work for my case.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to provide all the props correctly as Page A.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more of the code for this page. Such as where the component was imported in page B (to show that you're doing that).